# Is it possible to upload files by using inno setup?

Tags: upload, ftp, inno-setup

I'm searching for a way to upload my installation log files at the post install by using inno-setup. the upload is to my FTP server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to call FTP.EXE as a post-install job after installation. This can be done in code as described in the InnoSetup help file. Please be aware of the fact that user name and password of your FTP server would have to be stored in the setup file - you might want to create some sort of anonymous account before you get going...

Comment: Tanks a lot. It was very helpful. Do you have any specific FTP.EXE to recommend?

Comment: There should be a FTP.EXE on any Windows system, I'd suppose it's in C:\Windows\System32.